# How to build an Organization Chart with highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I want to plot an organization chart with `highcharter` (or, optionally, with another R `highchart` plotting library). I know that there are already some questions about that topic but they seem outdated since highchart now offers the possibility of [organization chart](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/organization-chart).

Edit:
Due to the responses of raf18seb (thanks a lot for you insights), I tried to download the github version and run some code that mirrors the `sankey` logic. However, no plot is rendered:

```
devtools::install_github("jbkunst/highcharter")
library(highcharter)

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'organization') %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = list(
      list(from = 'Brazil', to = 'Portugal'),
      list(from = 'Brazil', to = 'Spain'),
      list(from = 'Poland', to = 'England'))
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the [feature request](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/567) by @raf18seb, currently we can build an organization chart as follows:

```
devtools::install_github("jbkunst/highcharter", ref = "720")
library(highcharter)

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'organization') %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = list(
      list(from = 'Brazil', to = 'Portugal'),
      list(from = 'Brazil', to = 'Spain'),
      list(from = 'Poland', to = 'England'))
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Organization series was added to Highcharts from v7.1.0, but Highcharter uses v7.0.1.

After Highcharter is updated, you should be able to use Organization chart using below syntax:

**Organization series inherits from Sankey.**

And this R code works for Sankey:

```
library(highcharter)

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'sankey') %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = list(
      list(from = 'Brazil', to = 'Portugal', weight = 5),
      list(from = 'Brazil', to = 'Spain', weight = 2),
      list(from = 'Poland', to = 'England', weight = 2))
  )
```

So all you need to do is to change **type: 'sankey'** to **type: 'organization'**.

Tested here in JS: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q8x06jga

Of course, you don't need **weight** value.

Comment: I checked the [github version](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/commit/a84a5d42add775ef28c4b4807509a436258b2a64#diff-4d05381fd762712313e748de35173db2) and to me it looks like they updated highcharter to use v7.2.0. After installing the dev version from github it could be used, couldnt it? However, I still have no clue about the syntax. Using the code above just yields the error "The quosure environment should be explicitly supplied as `env`" which seems rather unrelated to `highcharter`

Comment: Unfortunately, no plot is rendered. I updated my question with the code I used.

Comment: I created a ticket on Highcharter repo: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/567

I'll let you know if I get any feedback. You can follow the above ticket too

Comment: Thank you! I was going to to the same :)

Comment: The problem has been solved on a dev branch and I postet an answer myself. I appreciate your effort!