# Highcharter Dependency Wheel not showing up?

Tags: r, highcharts

I am trying to plot the Dependency Wheel Diagram type from Highcharter, but the plot didn't show up, is there anything I can do to make it show? It works fine with the Sankey Type

```
highchart() %>%
     hc_chart(type = 'sankey') %>%
     hc_add_series(
         data = list(
             list(from = 'Brazil', to = 'Portugal', weight = 5),
             list(from = 'Brazil', to = 'Spain', weight = 2),
             list(from = 'Poland', to = 'England', weight = 2)
             )
         )
```

[image]

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'dependencywheel') %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = list(
      list(from = 'Brazil', to = 'Portugal', weight = 5),
      list(from = 'Brazil', to = 'Spain', weight = 2),
      list(from = 'Poland', to = 'England', weight = 2)
    )
  )
```

(Nothing Shows up)

Here is my `sessionInfo()` output

[image]

(@Edit) Tried to download the branch reference @raf18seb suggested, but cannot open it directly

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this package, that I can say it as a Highcharter Sankey & Dependency Wheel Shortcut for R

```
devtools::install_github('czxa/sankeywheel', build_vignettes = TRUE)
library(data.table)
library(sankeywheel)
```

To Build Sankey based plot use:

```
sankeywheel(from = sankeydf$from,
            to = sankeydf$to,
            weight = sankeydf$weight,
            type = "sankey", 
            width = "100%",
            theme = "sandsignika",
            title = "Export Distribution between Countries")
```

[image]

To Build Dependency Wheel based plot use:

```
sankeywheel(from = sankeydf$from,
            to = sankeydf$to,
            weight = sankeydf$weight,
            type = "dependencywheel", 
            width = "100%",
            theme = "sandsignika",
            title = "Export Distribution between Countries")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Highcharts Dependency wheel in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59794724/highcharts-dependency-wheel-in-r) and [How to build an Organization Chart with highcharter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58540244/how-to-build-an-organization-chart-with-highcharter)

Try to install the highcharter package from this branch:

```
devtools::install_github("jbkunst/highcharter", ref = "720")
```

Comment: i tried to download to the specific branch, but it seems I can't open it directly, 404: Not Found

Comment: Probably it's been removed already. Previously I created a GitHub ticket on Highcharter repo here: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/567 - feel free to reopen it

Comment: okay thanks @raf18seb for pointing :), already commenting it up in there for the issues