# How can we plot Highcarts organization chart in R language?

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts

We are trying to plot this organization chart from https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/organization-chart in R language

We have build this plot with highcharter library of R but we can not develop this plot to what we want
[image]

```
devtools::install_github("jbkunst/highcharter")
library(highcharter)
highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'organization') %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = list(
    list(from = 'Share Holders', to = 'Board'),
      list(from = 'Board', to = 'Grethe Hjetland CEO'),
      list(from = 'Grethe Hjetland CEO', to = 'Christer Vasseng CTO'),
      list(from = 'Grethe Hjetland CEO', to = 'Anita Nesse CPO'),
      list(from = 'Grethe Hjetland CEO', to = 'Vidar Brekke CMO'),
      list(from = 'Anita Nesse CPO', to = 'Sales manager'),
      list(from = 'Anita Nesse CPO', to = 'WEB')
    ),color = 'red'
  )
```

What we want is...

[image]

And here it's source code https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/organization-chart

Here is JavaScript code is (You can see also in source code all Html Css and JavaScript)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    height: 600,
    inverted: true
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Org Chart'
  },

  accessibility: {
    point: {
      descriptionFormatter: function(point) {
        var nodeName = point.toNode.name,
          nodeId = point.toNode.id,
          nodeDesc = nodeName === nodeId ? nodeName : nodeName + ', ' + nodeId,
          parentDesc = point.fromNode.id;
        return point.index + '. ' + nodeDesc + ', reports to ' + parentDesc + '.';
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    type: 'organization',
    name: 'Highsoft',
    keys: ['from', 'to'],
    data: [
      ['Shareholders', 'Board'],
      ['Board', 'CEO'],
      ['CEO', 'CTO'],
      ['CEO', 'CPO'],
      ['CEO', 'CSO'],
      ['CEO', 'CMO'],
      ['CEO', 'HR'],
      ['CTO', 'Product'],
      ['CTO', 'Web'],
      ['CSO', 'Sales'],
      ['CMO', 'Market']
    ],
    levels: [{
      level: 0,
      color: 'silver',
      dataLabels: {
        color: 'black'
      },
      height: 25
    }, {
      level: 1,
      color: 'silver',
      dataLabels: {
        color: 'black'
      },
      height: 25
    }, {
      level: 2,
      color: '#980104'
    }, {
      level: 4,
      color: '#359154'
    }],
    nodes: [{
      id: 'Shareholders'
    }, {
      id: 'Board'
    }, {
      id: 'CEO',
      title: 'CEO',
      name: 'Grethe Hjetland',
      image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/12132317/Grethe.jpg'
    }, {
      id: 'HR',
      title: 'HR/CFO',
      name: 'Anne Jorunn Fjærestad',
      color: '#007ad0',
      image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/12132314/AnneJorunn.jpg',
      column: 3,
      offset: '75%'
    }, {
      id: 'CTO',
      title: 'CTO',
      name: 'Christer Vasseng',
      column: 4,
      image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/12140620/Christer.jpg',
      layout: 'hanging'
    }, {
      id: 'CPO',
      title: 'CPO',
      name: 'Torstein Hønsi',
      column: 4,
      image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/12131849/Torstein1.jpg'
    }, {
      id: 'CSO',
      title: 'CSO',
      name: 'Anita Nesse',
      column: 4,
      image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/12132313/Anita.jpg',
      layout: 'hanging'
    }, {
      id: 'CMO',
      title: 'CMO',
      name: 'Vidar Brekke',
      column: 4,
      image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/13105551/Vidar.jpg',
      layout: 'hanging'
    }, {
      id: 'Product',
      name: 'Product developers'
    }, {
      id: 'Web',
      name: 'Web devs, sys admin'
    }, {
      id: 'Sales',
      name: 'Sales team'
    }, {
      id: 'Market',
      name: 'Marketing team'
    }],
    colorByPoint: false,
    color: '#007ad0',
    dataLabels: {
      color: 'white'
    },
    borderColor: 'white',
    nodeWidth: 65
  }],
  tooltip: {
    outside: true
  },
  exporting: {
    allowHTML: true,
    sourceWidth: 800,
    sourceHeight: 600
  }

});
```

Can anyone help us to plot this organization chart in R language or is it possible to run JavaScript code in R in order to get this chart?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build an Organization Chart with highcharter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58540244/how-to-build-an-organization-chart-with-highcharter)

Comment: No I have used this code and you can see the output of this code in the first picture in my post Actually I want to develop this plot to the second picture(Second picture is developed with JavaScript) Do you have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you have a sample code:

```
library(highcharter)

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = 'organization', inverted = TRUE) %>%
  hc_title(text = 'Highcharts Org Chart') %>%
  hc_add_series(
    name = 'Highsoft',
    data = list(
      list(from = 'Shareholders', to = 'Board'),
      list(from = 'Board', to = 'CEO'),
      list(from = 'CEO', to = 'CTO'),
      list(from = 'CEO', to = 'CPO'),
      list(from = 'CEO', to = 'CSO'),
      list(from = 'CEO', to = 'CMO'),
      list(from = 'CEO', to = 'HR'),
      list(from = 'CTO', to = 'Product'),
      list(from = 'CTO', to = 'Web'),
      list(from = 'CSO', to = 'Sales'),
      list(from = 'CMO', to = 'Market')
    ),
    levels = list(
      list(level = 0, color = 'silver', dataLabels = list(color = 'black'), height = 55),
      list(level = 1, color = 'silver', dataLabels = list(color = 'black'), height = 55),
      list(level = 2, color = '#980104'),
      list(level = 4, color = '#359154')
    ),
    nodes = list(
      list(id = 'Shareholders'),
      list(id = 'Board'),
      list(id = 'CEO', title = 'CEO', name = 'Grethe Hjetland', image = 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/12132317/Grethe.jpg'),
      list(id = 'HR', title = 'HR/CFO', name = 'Anne Jorunn Fjarestad', color = '#007ad0', image = 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/12132314/AnneJorunn.jpg', column = 3, offset = '75%'),
      list(id = 'CTO', title = 'CTO', name = 'Christer Vasseng', color = '#007ad0', image = 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/12140620/Christer.jpg', column = 4, layout = 'hanging'),
      list(id = 'CPO', title = 'CPO', name = 'Torstein Honsi', image = 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/12131849/Torstein1.jpg', column = 4),
      list(id = 'CSO', title = 'CSO', name = 'Anita Nesse', image = 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/12132313/Anita.jpg', column = 4, layout = 'hanging'),
      list(id = 'CMO', title = 'CMO', name = 'Vidar Brekke', image = 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/13105551/Vidar.jpg', column = 4, layout = 'hanging'),
      list(id = 'Product', name = 'Product developers'),
      list(id = 'Web', name = 'Web devs, sys admin'),
      list(id = 'Sales', name = 'Sales team'),
      list(id = 'Market', name = 'Marketing team')
    ),
    colorByPoint = TRUE,
    color = '#007ad0',
    dataLabels = list(color = 'white'),
    borderColor = 'white',
    nodeWidth = 65
  ) %>%
  hc_tooltip(outside = TRUE)
```

You can see the R structure. If you want to use JavaScript code in it, you can use JS() method. More examples of Highcharts in R (with JS() method) you can find in my StackOverflow profile in 'Answers' tab.

Let me know if you have further questions.

edit: some properties (like color) don't work in Highcharter wrapper. I suggest creating a GitHub ticket on Highcharter repo: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues
Maybe the author of the wrapper will know more.

Comment: Thanks, this is super helpful! I tried using images  of people that are stored as JPGs on the computer, but that did not work. Is it somehow possible to make it work, or do the images have to be online?

Comment: @raf18seb why is the rules of your levels list please ? It seems that the code is still working well without and returning the same chart.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question, could you ask one more time? Are you asking about "levels" list? You can find details in the API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.organization.levels